# Reading csv from url and pushing it in DB through pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

The URL gives a csv formatted data. I am trying to get the data and push it in database. However, I am unable to read data as it only prints header of the file and not complete csv data. Could there be better option?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("some-url") //URL not provided due to security restrictions. 

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Can you provide an URL so we could reproduce it?

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that URL couldn't be provided due to security restrictions. But it does give out a csv data.  

response.headers['content-type']) output: 
text/csv; charset=utf-8

response.encoding output:
utf-8

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help you not being able to reproduce this issue. If you read your URL using `requests` - does its contents look like a plain CSV file?

Comment: I know it would be difficult. 
It is plain csv data. 

response.context output:
`b'click_id,do_id....0\r\n'`

response.text output:
`click_id,do_id,...`
`83928382,82387283,...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate through the results of `df.to_dict(orient="records")`:

```
data = pd.read_csv("some-url")
for row in data.to_dict(orient="records"):
    # For each loop, `row` will be filled with a key:value dict where each
    # key takes the value of the column name.
    # Use this dict to create a record for your db insert, eg as raw SQL or
    # to create an instance for an ORM like SQLAlchemy.
```

I do a similar thing to pre-format data for SQLAlchemy inserts, although I'm using Pandas to merge data from multiple sources rather than just reading the file.

*Side note: There will be plenty of other ways to do this without Pandas and just iterate through the lines of the file. However Pandas's intuituve handling of CSVs makes it an attractive shortcut to do what you need.*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you sir.